# When I combine two lists and put the new list through a few functions. Is there a way to identify which original list a specific value is from?

Tags: python, numpy

I combined the lists like this `allSpeed = np.concatenate((smallspeed, bigspeed))`. I then sorted it and took the 100 smallest values. I now need to identify how many of each came from the original lists. Is this possible?

Comment: Are all the values unique ? Are all the smallest values always in smallspeed ? If not I am afraid you cannot.

Comment: you would have to create lists with pairs `(value, "smallspeed")` and `(value, "bigpeed")` and when you combine and sort it then you will have value and information from which list is this value.

Comment: `allSpeed` is a new array, without any history or indication of how it was constructed, except for the obvious original position.  The first `n` values come from the array that's `n` elements long etc.  I can imagine using `argsort` on `allSpeed`, and deducing from that which values came from which source array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

If you use `argsort`, you will get the indices of the sort order, e.g.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 4, 0, 2])
print(np.argsort(a))   # => [2, 0, 3, 1]
```

Depending on whether you need the actual sorted values or just to know how many came from each array, you can work directly from the argsort result:

```py
smallspeed = np.array([1, 3, 2, 5])
bigspeed = np.array([4, 0, 6]
all_speed = np.concatenate((smallspeed, bigspeed))
sort_order = np.argsort(all_speed)
lowest_4 = sort_order[:4]  # or 100 for your case
small_count = np.count_nonzero(lowest_4 < len(smallspeed))
big_count = 4 - small_count
# or
big_count = np.count_nonzero(lowest_4 >= len(smallspeed))
```

Note that you will need to decide what it means if there are values that appear in both arrays and that value happens to be at the 100 value cutoff. This approach will give you an answer according to where each value came from, but that won't necessarily be meaningful. You will need to consider which sort algorithm you wish to use and which order you concatenate your arrays. For example, if you want to preferentially count "small speeds" in the lowest 100 when there are duplicates, then concatenate small + big (as you currently have), and use a stable sorting algorithm.

Comment: @AyanGuha you're welcome. If this answers your question, please vote it up and mark it as accepted (the arrow and the tick on the left of the question, respectively)